# Get the random value and Specific value ,if the specifc string Found inbetween these values using java

Tags: java

I have One Excel File and One Text File.
Here is the sample whereas my original Files are too long -https://pastebin.com/iCua7BCs
I want to Compare Excel value with the Text File Content.
The Text File contains group of strings.Each Group Enclosed inbetween 
Someword (Eg:AnotherData(12)) and END
If value (Find3) Found. I want to Get the particular word (AnotherData(12)) and END 
It will be helpfull if someone suggest a way.
Here is the code:

```
        import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.File;
        import java.io.FileInputStream;
        import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
        import java.io.FileOutputStream;
        import java.io.FileReader;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.nio.file.Files;
        import java.nio.file.Paths;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.Arrays;
        import java.util.Iterator;
        import java.util.List;
        import java.util.logging.Level;
        import java.util.logging.Logger;
        import java.util.regex.Matcher;
        import java.util.regex.Pattern;
        import javax.swing.JButton;
        import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
        import org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException;
        import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
        import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile;
        import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.Sheet;
        import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
        import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
        import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
        import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
        import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
        import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
        import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
        import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
        import sun.nio.cs.StandardCharsets;

        public class NewClass{
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        FileInputStream f;
        f = new FileInputStream("C://Users//HP//Documents//Sample.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook (f);
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        String text = 
        new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("D://Sample.txt")));
        String []tx_sp=text.split("\n");
        for(Row r:sheet){
        Cell c=r.getCell(0);
        String cellContents = c.getStringCellValue();
        String[] words = cellContents.split("\\s+");
        for (int i = 0, l = words.length; i + 1 < l; i++){
        for(String fx:tx_sp){
        if (fx.contains(words[i])){
        System.out.println(words[i]+"*"+fx);
        }

        }

        }}}
        }
```

In this code I Compared the Excel content and Text File Content .If the Excel Value  Found in Text File.I can get that specific line.

Problem: How to get the random value and Specific value where that specific line is enclosed.

I want to get this(if Find3 is the Excel Value)

```
    AnotherData(12)  
    But not every valid Find3 parentheses sequence will satisfy him
    END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way...
Instead of spilting your text by **'\n'**, spilt it by **'END'**

```
String []tx_sp=text.split("END");  //END will not contain in String
```

And in loop

```
for(String fx:tx_sp)  //your for loop
{                                        
String temparray[]= fx.split("\n");
  for (int x = 1; x < temparray.length;  x++)
  {
    if (temparray[x].contains(words[i]))
    {
     System.out.println(temparray[0]+     // It will have  AnotherData(12)
                        temparray[x]+     // It will have matched line with Find3
                        "END");           // Append an END which is omitted by split method
      break;                              // breaks the loop if Find3 found
    }
  }
}
```

It is just an idea how you can do this, there are other better ways.
You can optimize it further

Answer (score 0):

Finally I Got the Required Result ..Thanks to @Tarun

```
try {
        FileInputStream f;
        f = new FileInputStream("C://Users//HP//Documents//sample.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook (f);
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        String text = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("D://sample.txt")));
        String []tx_sp=text.split("END");
        for(Row r:sheet){
        Cell c=r.getCell(0);
        String cellContents = c.getStringCellValue();
        String[] words = cellContents.split("\\s+");
        for(String fx:tx_sp)  
        for (int i = 0, l = words.length; i + 1 < l; i++){
        {    
        String temparray[]= fx.split("\n");
        for (int j = 1; j< temparray.length;  j++)
        {
        if (temparray[j].contains(words[i]))
        {if(temparray[0].contains("(")){
        System.out.println(temparray[0]);
        System.out.println(words[i]+"*"+temparray[j]);
        break;                         
        }
        }
        }
        }
        }}
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Split.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Split.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```